# Scroll Page 100 Pxiels If Width > 915 pxiels using function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why is this script not working ?
i wish to scroll page 100 pixels on click of a button only if the page width exceeds 915 pixels . I am trying to do so by allowing the function to run only if the width exceeds 915 pixels but it is not happening. how to do it?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if(window.innerWidth > 915) {
    function scrollDown() {
      window.scrollBy(0, 100);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Maybe because you just define this function instead of executing?

Comment: `if ( $(window).width() > 915 ) $(window).scrollTop(100)` <- that's **all** you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you only define the `scrollDown()` function, you don't call it. The function itself is redundant. You can just call `scrollBy()` directly. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (window.innerWidth > 915) {
    window.scrollBy(0, 100);
  }
});
```

Also note that this will only run on load of the page. If you want to do this on click of a button you need to add a button click event handler, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#yourButton').click(function() {
    if (window.innerWidth > 915) {
      window.scrollBy(0, 100);
    }
  }).click(); // remove .click() here if you don't want to run the code on load
});
```